# how to use json and ajax two dimension array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

here i have created function for calling json but its not working......how to call it?

```
function get_company_expenses_type(element_id){   $.ajax({
         url: "../../modal/get_companyexpenses_type.php", 
         dataType: "html",
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(json){

            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            length=result.length;
            for(k=1;k<=length;k++) {
             $('#'+element_id+' option').last().after('<option value="result.'+row1.company_expenses_type_id+'">'+result.row1.company_expenses_type+'</option>');
             }      
             }     });
         } $(document).ready(function(){

         var cnt = 1;    $("#anc_add").click(function(){
         cnt++;
         $("input[id=rows]").val(cnt);
         $('#tbl1 tr').last().after('<tr><td><select name="'+cnt+'1"><option value="0">Select Expenses    Type</option>X</select></td><td><textarea    name="'+cnt+'2"></textarea></td><td><input type="text"    name="'+cnt+'3"></td></tr>');    });
           get_company_expenses_type('11');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `dataType: "html"` to `dataType: "json"`, if you are expecting a JSON response`application/json` from server.

From [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server

Also no need of using `var result = jQuery.parseJSON(json);`. This can be used when you return a json formatted string`text/plain` response from server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things in your code:

#### -First:

change

```
dataType:"html"
```

to

```
dataType:"json"
```

because the request returns `json` as this seems to be in your post.

#### -Second:

In your code i just saw you are targeting the id which is not there:

```
$('#'+element_id+' option')
```

so this has to be:

```
$('[name*="'+element_id+'"] option')
```

Comment: in your function change the dataType as mentioned and also in your success callback change the selector as mentioned.